# Combat on a spiral staircase

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, terrain

Are there any rules regarding combat on a spiral staircase?
In real life, castle-towers had spiral staircases designed to give a definitive advantage to the defending party, always spiraling in such a way that the person on top walking backwards can more easily swing their weapon than the one below trying to climb it.

I was wondering if there were any official D&D rules that reflect this. Are there any bonuses / penalties when fighting on a spiral staircase? Any particular weapons that suffer further penalties, or are exempt to certain penalties?

Comment: ARather than have the comments fill up with chat about spiral staircases, please reserve comments for their [intended administrative purposes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). For questions or answers of why spiral staircases were built, consider posting on [history.se] SE under the \[[architecture](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture)\] tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [Stairs](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#stairs) on [Spiral Stairs](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#spiral-stairs) says

> This form of steep stairs is designed to make defending a fortress easier. Characters gain [cover](http://dndsrd.net/combatModifiers.html#cover) against foes below them on spiral stairs because they can easily duck around the staircase’s central support. (63)

(Link added.) Because spiral stairs are, by default, steep stairs, it's also useful to keep in mind the rules for [Steep Stairs](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#steep-stairs):

> Characters moving up steep stairs (which rise at a 45-degree angle or steeper) must spend 2 squares of movement to enter each square of stairs. Characters running or charging down steep stairs must succeed on a DC 10 Balance check upon entering the first steep stairs square. Characters who fail stumble and must end their movement 1d2×5 feet later. Characters who fail by 5 or more take 1d6 points of damage and fall prone in the square where they end their movement. Steep stairs increase the DC of Tumble checks by 5. (*ibid.*)

Presumably, the bonus on attack rolls for higher ground should also be granted according to the entry on [Gradual Stairs](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#graudal-stairs):

> Stairs that rise less than 5 feet for every 5 feet of horizontal distance they cover don’t affect movement, but characters who attack a foe below them gain a +1 bonus on attack rolls from being on higher ground. Most stairs in dungeons are gradual, except for spiral stairs (see below).

Combined, these rules seem to simulate what the question desires: when all involved are on a spiral staircase, those who are above their foes are in a much more advantageous position than those who are below their foes, especially as the cover gained by those above prevents attacks of opportunity by those below!

---

***Note:*** While this should be enough detail for most engagements, Anauroch: Empire of Shade *on Steep Spiral Stairs largely repeats this information but adds some minor details about guiding a mount up and down steep spiral stairs (121).*

Answer (score 10):

#### +1 attack for higher ground

According to Favorable and Unfavorable Conditions (Player's Handbook, p.150-151) ([SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm)), if the attacker is on higher ground, they gain a +1 bonus to melee attacks.

Note that this is considered more of a guideline to DMs, who as per PHB p.150 are expected to adjudicate favorable and unfavorable conditions as they see fit. Likewise, the rules DM may impose an ad-hoc rule for certain weapons, although the +1 bonus for fighting from higher ground is the only bonus specifically defined in the rules.

Depending on the layout of the staircase, characters may have cover from each other, although this would equally benefit both attacker and defender. Note that this also prevents opportunity attacks.

The narrow layout of the tunnel limits the effectiveness of area spells or spells reliant on line of sight. While earlier editions of the game (AD&D) had fireballs expand to fill the area, D&D 3.5's is specifically just a sphere of fire fixed around a point, and won't fill an entire tunnel unless the DM is feeling particularly fiendish.

Historical castle staircases sometimes had a "trip step", which could cause an attacker to fall if they weren't aware of it. I would model this as a low-CR trap with maybe a DC or 12 to 14, which causes the person to fall prone; it can be avoided by simply stepping over it if you are aware of it, as the defenders would be. A prone target has -4 to his AC against melee attacks, and makes his own attacks at a -4 penalty. They have to take a move action to stand up, which significantly limits their combat options to a standard action on that turn.